# How to validate a date from a Calendar

Tags: java, validation, jsf-2, primefaces

I have tried the following code (I have followed an example) to test a date choosen from a calendar. If the date don't exist in my database, then a validation error message should be shown to the enduser. However, the error does not end up in the `<h:message>`, instead it is being logged to the server log.

View:

```xml
<p:calendar id="date1" value="#{bean.date1}" showOn="button"> 
    <f:validator validatorId="calendarValidator" />
    <f:ajax execute="date1" render="calendarmessage" />
</p:calendar>
<h:message id="calendarmessage" for="date1" />
```

Validator:

```
@FacesValidator("calendarValidator")
public class CalendarValidator implements Validator{

    @Override  
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        java.util.Date date2 = (java.util.Date) value;

        try {
            if (validateDate(date2)) {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("A valid date"));
            } else {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("date dont figure in the database"));
            } 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Server log:

```
INFO: date invalide
GRAVE: javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException: date dont figure in the database
at DAOKPI.CalendarValidator.validate(CalendarValidator.java:60)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1149)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:967)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1
```

Comment: did you debug or use a breakpoint? Does your validateDate function ever return true? ........can you post your code for that?

Comment: To clarify, you're wondering why no message has been returned to the user?  As opposed to the fact that the correct exception appears to be caught?

Answer (score 4):

Look at your code once again, you're catching and printing the `ValidatorException` inside the validator yourself! You should not catch and log the `ValidatorException` yourself. You should let it go and let JSF catch and handle it so that it can display it in the message component accordingly.

**Get rid** of the `try` block in the validator and add the `throws` clause to the `validate()` method.

```
@Override  
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    java.util.Date date2 = (java.util.Date) value;

    if (validateDate(date2)) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("A valid date")); // Btw: I wonder how that makes sense... That's actually not a validation error.
    } else {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("date dont figure in the database"));
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank you very much ,your right I have followed your advise and it worked fine except the msg ,it was displayed  after submitting(I have a button validate the form) but I want the msg to be displayed just after picking the date in the same page!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the problem in the validator that @Balusc already mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847818/160206), you should use PrimeFaces-components consitently:

```
<p:calendar id="date1" value="#{bean.date1}" showOn="button"> 
    <f:validator validatorId="calendarValidator" />
    <p:ajax execute="date1" update="calendarmessage" />
</p:calendar>
<p:message id="calendarmessage" for="date1" />
```